# Exclusion Order Status

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-status, status

i am getting order from magento using this query which is fine

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));
```

currently i am getting order for all status but i want skip those ordres which oreder status is
Exclusions :

Order with any of the following status :

Cancelled
On Hold
Complete
Closed
Payment  Review
PayPal Cancelled Reversal
PayPal Reversed
Pending
Pending Payment
Pending  PayPal

how i acheive by query

Answer (score 0):

```
$skipStatuses = array(list all your status codes you want to skip here)
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('nin' => $skipStatuses));
```